# HTTP Status 404 for existing controller url

Tags: grails, controller, http-status-code-404

I added a new domain class named Authorization in my grails project in the package named RH.

Then I generated controller and views automatically from grails menu.

But when I tried to enter the URL of controller http://localhost:8080/RH/Authorization/list, apache displays `HTTP Status 404 - /RH/Authorization`

```
type Status report

message /RH/Authorization

description The requested resource (/RH/Authorization) is not available.
```

I refresh the project and I restart apache but same error persist.
There is another thing to do to solve the problem ?

Comment: Did you scaffold the view? you must have list.gsp or show us some code of your controller?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the package named RH"? If you are referring to Java packages, these are not taken account of in the default controller URL Mapping, so your url would just be http://localhost:8080/Authorization/list - unless you are using a non-root application context on your container in which case the URL would be http://localhost:8080/(context)/Authorization/list. To give an example, `grails run-app` sets the context to the current application name for the built-in Jetty, so the URL would be http://localhost:8080/MyApp/Authorization/list

Comment: yes, I have , there is a method named list in controller and list.groovy in views that is generated automatically by grails

Comment: @Poundex : thanks for your response, yes that the package is the same name at the name of application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ran the `generate-all` or `generate-controller` script the generated controller name would be AuthorizationController.groovy, and the convention for auto-mapping urls for controllers is to remove "Controller" from the class name (yes, this does get you back to the domain class name, but a controller can exist independent of any domain class, and you don't need the controller and domain class names to have anything in common) and generate the "property" name from that. Ordinarily this just involves lower-casing the first letter, but if the name starts with two or more uppercase letters then you don't change anything.

The package that the class name has no effect on the generated urls. But if you don't specify the package name when running the `create-domain-class` script, it will use the project name as the package, and the default context is also the same as the project name, so it can seem like the package name is used.

Are you really using Apache (httpd)? Or Apache Tomcat? If you're using Apache then the context is determined by how you connect Apache and the servlet container that Apache is fronting (Tomcat, Jetty, WebLogic, etc.)

Assuming you're using Tomcat by itself, the context is based on the name of the deployed war file, and if you're using `grails run-app` and using the embedded Tomcat server, it's based on the project name.

So I'm guessing that the core problem is that "Authorization" should be "authorization". Additionally, "RH" may be incorrect, but hopefully based on what I said above you can figure out what it should be.

Comment: I tried capitalizing the first letter of the controller and does not have effect ;it works( **you said "Authorization" should be "authorization"**)

Comment: you are right @Burt Beckwith, "Authorization" should be "authorization", it works now. Thanks!